# How bad is eval() to read function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used Hopscotch to make a guided tour through my Website. Now for that you have to make a JS object which will be the parameter to call the startTour() function which will initiate the Tour.
In this example a tour is started by clicking a a.hopscotch-start link.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="hopscotch-start" data-name="x">Start tour</a>
```

JS:

```
var x = {id: "tour1", steps: [{title: "the title",....}]};
$("a.hopscotch-start").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hopscotch.startTour(eval($(this).data('name'))); // -> startTour(x);
  return false;
}
```

How bad is this actually? I know that eval is "slow", but it would give me the flexibility to have just one general click code and not bother about it any more. What is the actual security risk, if any? And does that significantly slower the code (regarding the fact that the code is just reading a string to be parsed as a variable).

Thank you for your feedback - any other solution than eval to achieve the same is also welcome.

Comment: Instead of having variables `x`, `y`, etc., why not just have an object `o = {x: ..., y: ..., ...}` and use `hopscotch.startTour(o[$(this).data('name')]);` ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing it that quickly, would it have been an answer I'd have voted for that. Worked, and I feel stupid not having thought about it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make an object and get it by keys? It will be quicker and safer:

```
var tours = {
  x: {id: "tour1", steps: [{title: "the title",....}]},
  y: {id: "tour2", steps: [{title: "the title",....}]}
}
$("a.hopscotch-start").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hopscotch.startTour(tours[$(this).data('name')]); // -> startTour(x);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anything has in any way modified the value of the attribute, you've now executed arbitrary JavaScript from the server.

And the real question is: *Why?*

If you use an object as a lookup, there's no need for `eval`:

```
var data = {
  x: {...},
  y: {...},
  ...
};
$("a.hopscotch-start").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hopscotch.startTour(data[$(this).data('name')]);
}
```

Alternatively, it may make sense to just inline your data in the attribute itself:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<a href="#" class="hopscotch-start" data-hopscotch='{"id":"tour1","steps":[{"title":"the title",...}...]'>Start tour</a>
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$("a.hopscotch-start").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hopscotch.startTour($(this).data('hopscotch'));
}
```